# How to play video from Google Drive in Better Player - Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api, flutter-web, exoplayer, flutter-video-player

In my app, I already integrated with google login and I successfully accessed my google drive folder and video files(mp4). But better player can play public video by modified url like this `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=my_video_file_id`.
I want to develop an app like **Nplayer** or **Kudoplayer**.

Can anyone guide me some scenario of Nplayer or Kudoplayer? and guide me how to play private drive's video using better player. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Finally* I got solution after research for a long time :-)

*Summary answer for this question*

- Don't forget to add `headers` in `BetterPlayerDataSource`
- **Don't use** this format `"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=${fileId}"` and
- **Use** this format `"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?alt=media"`

---

For guys who face issue like me, please follow these step

- Enable Drive API
- Integrate google login in your app with appropriate `Scpoe`, for me `driveReadonlyScope` is enough.
- Retrieve `fileId`

*Next step that I stuck is*

- Don't forget to add `headers` in `BetterPlayerDataSource`
- **Don't use** this format `"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=${fileId}"` and
- **Use** this format `"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?alt=media"`

***Like this***

```
BetterPlayerDataSource betterPlayerDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
  BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
    "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$fileId?alt=media",
    videoExtension: ".mp4",
    headers: getDataFromCache(CacheManagerKey.authHeader),
 );
```

`authHeader` can get when you call *signWithGoogle* function,
I save it and retrieve later. In `signWithGoogle` function, you can get authHeader using this

```
Map<String, String> authHeader = await googleSignIn.currentUser!.authHeaders;
```

***Bonus - Queries For You.***

- Get Share With Me Data = > `q: "'sharedWithMe = true and (mimeType = 'video/mp4' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder')"`
- Get Share Drive Data => `q: "'shared_drive_id' in parents and trashed=false and (mimeType = 'video/mp4' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder')"`,
- Get My Drive Data => `q: "'root' in parents and trashed=false and (mimeType = 'video/mp4' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder')"`,

Comment: Hi there, are you going to ask the user to login with google first????

Comment: is it going to work with large videos to play

Comment: do you have project on GitHub?

Comment: @FaizanAhmad This is my WIP project and I changed it public temporarily, You can reference. https://github.com/waihanko/chill_player

Comment: @FTFStudio Yes, user need to login first to access his related drive's videos and it work with large video file

Answer (score 0):

that's tricky.

I would propably try to attach approprieate headers so google drive would allow me to reach file using `BetterPlayerDataSource class`.

but being curious and checking how google would want it to be made... I got into spiral of google docs and I found this

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enhancing-security-controls-for-google-drive-third-party-apps

Keep in mind that downloading file and streaming also differ. So if you want for your player to not lag you should stream.

Comment: Can you share sample header for BetterPlayerDataSource?. I already tested with all drive scope but not working. Thanks!

Comment: @WaiHanKo Sorry I have replied openly. I have never been doing it. I was just pointing direction what I would do.